# MongoDB can't to start mongos (sharding)

Tags: mongodb

I study mongo and now I have problem when I try to connect to mongos
This is what I doing
1
create shard1

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --install --serviceName "Mongo DB Shard 1"  --serviceDisplayName "Mongo DB Shard 1" --port 10001 --dbpath C:\s1 --logpath C:\s1\log.txt
```

and shard2

```
 C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --install --serviceName "Mongo DB Shard 2"  --serviceDisplayName "Mongo DB Shard 2" --port 10002 --dbpath C:\s2 --logpath C:\s2\log.txt
```

After create manager (mongos)

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongos.exe --install --port 10003  --serviceDisplayName "MongoRouter"  --serviceDescription "MongoDB Sharding Router" --configdb localhost:10000 --logpath C:\MongosRouter\routerLog.txt
```

After I start this as services

Next step I in cmd create command `cd c:\mongodb\bin` and `mongo localhost:10003`
butafter last command, cmd freeze and nothing to do. Where I`am mistake?
Please help me!

Comment: try like mongo --port 10003

Comment: I dont't understand. Where try?

Comment: while trying to connect mongos on third step.. use mongo --port 10003 instead of mongo localhost:10003

Comment: write error: coudn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:10003 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147

Comment: then use ip.. mongo --host:[ip]:10003 .. replace ip with mongos ip

Comment: `mongos` is not able to connect to `localhost:10000`. You need to start another `mongod` on `localhost:10000` acting as config server.

Answer (score 0):

- What does your MongoS log file say - "C:\MongosRouter\routerLog.txt"? Is it running?
- As part of MongoS you specified the config server as "--configdb localhost:10000", you don't seem to have mentioned if you started a config db in your question. Did you start MongoD instance for config DB? If not, you'll need to start one and most likely you'll see this as the reason why your MongoS is failing in the log file as well.
- If the config DB was started, can check further on MongoS log files on any specific issue why it is not running.
- If MongoS is running, may be check windows firewall, if it is blocking the connections. May be try turning off the windows firewall and see if you are able to connect.